# Pandas / SQL Datatype Difficulties?

Tags: python, mysql, stock-data

I have some data that looks like this

```
    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Instrument
Date                        
2018-09-02 07:00:00-04:00   7269.0  7274.0  7213.0  7240.5  2321665 XBTZ18
2018-09-02 08:00:00-04:00   7240.5  7270.0  7240.5  7259.0  781280  XBTZ18
2018-09-02 09:00:00-04:00   7259.0  7259.5  7161.0  7194.5  2959099 XBTZ18
2018-09-02 10:00:00-04:00   7194.5  7238.0  7189.5  7232.0  1799117 XBTZ18
2018-09-02 11:00:00-04:00   7232.0  7245.0  7231.0  7235.0  237230  XBTZ18
```

Where the datatypes are:

```
Open          float64
High          float64
Low           float64
Close         float64
Volume          int64
Instrument     object
dtype: object
```

Now, I am just trying to write this pandas dataframe to a SQL data on Amazon AWS.

My table is structured as such

```
'Date' -- > DATETIME (Primary Key, Not Null, Unique)
'Open' -- > DECIMAL
'High' -- > Decimal
'Low' -- > Decimal
'Close' -- > Decimal
'Volume' -- > INT
'INSTRUMENT' -- > VarChar(45) (Primary Key, Not Null)
```

Now I would like to write my dataframe to SQL database:

```
df_for_db = data_dump[['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Instrument']]
#df_for_db['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(pd.Timestamp)

#write the dataframe
df_for_db.to_sql(name='hourlyData', con=engine, if_exists = 'replace', index=False)
```

but I get this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot cast DatetimeIndex to dtype datetime64[us]
```

The datatypes as seen above should be compatible, right? What am I missing? THank you

Comment: did you solve the problem?